# LiveCycle Designer | Populate Dropdown List from remote server

Tags: pdf, adobe, livecycle, pdf-form

I have one form with one dropdown list without any items. How To populate dropdownlist from remote server (xml/text/json/other via http request by URL)? It's possible or not?

Something like this [image]

I use Adobe LiveCycle Designer ES 4

Comment: You may want to take a look at webservice part of the data connection. You can use GET request to webservices and use the results as connection. Is it something you want?

Comment: @ph6 yes. how to make it?